# I can't get the object from action as Json Formatting using ajax post in mvc core

Tags: json, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc

```
 $(document).on("click", "#StudentDelete", function () {
        var Id = $(this).attr("data-id");
        alert(gelenId);
        $.ajax({
            url: '/SchoolRepo/DeleteStudent/' + Id,
            type: "POST",
            datatype: "Json",
            success: function (response) {
                if (response.Success) {
                    location.reload();
                    alert(response.Message);
                }
                else {
                    alert(response.Message);
                }
            }
        });

    });
```

---

```
public class ResultJson
{
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
 public IActionResult DeleteStudent(int id)
    {
        var student = db.Students.FirstOrDefault(q => q.Id == id);
        if (student!=null)
        {
            db.Students.Remove(student);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return Json(new  ResultJson { Message = "Student is deleted successfully", Success=true });
        }
        return Json(new ResultJson { Message = "Student is not deleted", Success = false });
    }
```

when I use these code snappets I can't get 'Response.Message' or 'Response.Success' values. always returned 'undefined'. when I used the same codes in mvc 5 I could get values. what is the reason ? thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON result in ASP.NET Core MVC is using camel case naming strategy by default while serializing the result. So the result will get returned as shown below.

> {"success":true,"message":"Student is deleted successfully"}

You can access the result as **response.success** and **response.message**

I hope this help you.

https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/760c8f38678118734399c58c2dac981ea6e47046/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json/JsonSerializerSettingsProvider.cs